# Is there an R function for sorting list elements using one of its elements?

Tags: r, list, sorting

I am doing some simulations, and I have a list where the first element is a vector with certain coefficients calculated using values from corresponding (simulated) data frames, and the second element is a list where those corresponding data frames are stored.

```
Results[[1]][[i]] # returns a coefficient
Results[[2]][[i]] # returns a corresponding data frame
```

I would like to sort the elements by the coefficients, so that the highest coefficient and corresponding data frame would be at the first place, the second best solution in the second place, etc. I am able to get the highest coefficient by using which.max() function, and the database by running Results[[2]][[which.max(Results[[1]])]]. However, I would like to get other databases with high coefficients. My questions is, is there a simple solution for sorting the list in this way?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each element in `Results[[1]]` is a single number, we can use the `order` function:

```
set.seed(123)
l1 <- replicate(10,{runif(1)},simplify=F) # Results1 equivalent
l2 <- lapply(1:10,function(x) return(x)) # Results2 equivalent
l1
[1]]
[1] 0.2875775

[[2]]
[1] 0.7883051

[[3]]
[1] 0.4089769

[[4]]
[1] 0.8830174

[[5]]
[1] 0.9404673

[[6]]
[1] 0.0455565

[[7]]
[1] 0.5281055

[[8]]
[1] 0.892419

[[9]]
[1] 0.551435

[[10]]
[1] 0.4566147

l2
> l2
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5

[[6]]
[1] 6

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] 8

[[9]]
[1] 9

[[10]]
[1] 10

l2 <- l2[order(unlist(l1), decreasing =T)]
l2
> l2
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 8

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 2

[[5]]
[1] 9

[[6]]
[1] 7

[[7]]
[1] 10

[[8]]
[1] 3

[[9]]
[1] 1

[[10]]
[1] 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a simple solution and good explanation!